# Identifying differences between two images using OpenIMAJ

Tags: java, image-processing, object-detection, openimaj

I am working on an image processing project. I am using two images taken from the same webcam from the same stationary position.

one is an image of a surface, (like my table)

another is of the same surface, but with an object placed in the field of view.

I am trying to separate the new object in the second image from the background available in the first image.

I am new to image processing and the OpenIMAJ library. If anyone could tell me what functions or techniques I could use to achieve this, it would be of great help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If the two images are from the same view-point, you can try background subtraction.

Comment: Hi @GilLevi, Thank you for your comment. I am using background subtraction for performing the task.